# When does an operation not include execution?

Tags: graphql

According to the [GraphQL specification](http://facebook.github.io/graphql/October2016/#sec-Response-Format):

> #### Response Format
>
> A response to a GraphQL operation must be a map.
>
> If the operation **included execution**, the response map must contain a first entry with key data.

When does a GraphQL operation not include execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only case I can think of is the following section (right below the one you quoted):

> The response map may also contain an entry with key extensions. This
>   entry, if set, must have a map as its value. This entry is reserved
>   for implementors to extend the protocol however they see fit, and
>   hence there are no additional restrictions on its contents.

So, in theory, there might be a server that returns the following response, given a GraphQL document:

```
{
  "extensions": {
    "message": "ACK"
  }
}
```

I have never seen such a server in practice, but a server acting like this is GraphQL spec compliant.